# Present Continuous vs Future Simple

Tags: grammar

> 1)   They are driving to New York tomorrow morning. (Present Continuous)
>   2)   I'll be in the office tomorrow morning. (Future Simple)

Why can't you use the Future Simple in the first question?
Why is the Future Simple used in the second question?

Answer (score 1):

1. We use the present continuous to talk about A FIXED PLAN in future or some future event already decided.

> *"They are driving to New York tomorrow morning."*

2. When you are making a decision, use **will**:

> *"I'll be in the office tomorrow morning".*

Comment: Thank you your answer was very useful

Answer (score 1):

Driving is an activity that takes some time, whereas being at the office is a state. For states, we tend to use a simple tense, and for activities that take some time, we tend to use a continuous tense.

Read the section about using [present simple](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-simple) and [present continuous](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/present-continuous) to describe future events in this British Council pages. To summarise, you can use present simple for fixed, timetabled or planned events, and present continuous to describe future plans. Both of the sentences that you quoted are future plans: they plan to drive to New York, and you plan to be in the office. You can use a present tense for both.

Being at the office is a state, so future simple is fine: it's a plan, so you could also use present simple:

> I am in the office tomorrow morning

Driving is an activity, not a state. The people are planning to drive to New York, so it's OK to use present continuous, but you can also use future continuous:

> They will be driving to New York tomorrow morning.

Comment: Thanks for your useful answer